# how to fold only functions, methods in notepad++

Tags: netbeans, notepad++, folding

I like the way netbeans folds functions and methods automatically when opening the file. I use notepad++ as well but when I use folding it will fold everything including html, if else conditions and functions. I would love to have the option to fold functions only. Does anyone know any plug-in that does that or maybe there is a setting somewhere in notepad++ that I missed.

Thanks

Comment: The minus signs at the left margin?

Comment: I want to fold all the functions with one key shortcut

Answer (score 9):

There is a level shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd> (<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>) to fold and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>) to Unfold
It folds everything in the same level:

```
level 2
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Source](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm).

Comment: The number has to be typed from the top row of the keyboard, not the number pad (which types symbols).